# Google speech-to-text API key not valid

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I just following the Google-speech-to-text API examples.. 
reading quickstart guide.

but it has some trouble...

just curl command in this.

I just tried to change the Credential keys ..

but still not working .

just using windows and powershell.

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)
```

`https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize -d @sync-request.json`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the URL to the guide you are following?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-protocol?hl=ko i just follow this URL  maybe i just confused Credentials step.. so, i just erase key file and modify it or make new one,, many times.. probably twisted these process..